# PHP MIME Type, limit uploading file

Tags: php

I have this code

```
if(isset($_FILES['uploadfile']))   
    {  
    $maxsize    = 10485760; //10MBx1024
    $acceptable = array(
        'image/jpeg',       
        'image/jpg',
        'image/gif',
        'image/png',
        'application/pdf',
        'text/plain',
        'application/vnd.ms-excel',
        'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet',
        'application/vnd.ms-word',
        'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document',
        'application/zip',
        'application/x-zip-compressed',
        'application/x-compressed',
        );
```

and this is the following parts:

```
if((!in_array($_FILES['uploadfile']['type'], $acceptable)) && (!empty($_FILES["uploadfile"]["type"]))) 
{
$msg= "<b><img src=redwarn.png'><font color='red'> This file is not accepted.</b></font>";  

goto cancel; 
}
```

The above code could limit the extension that user upload, but I tried to upload a IMAGE file, it come out an error that the file wasn't accepted, but I did add `'image/jpeg'` in the array, is there any error in my code?

Thanks

Comment: You're asking if there is any errors with this code? Have *you* seen any problems? Or is this just a code review request?

Comment: If this is a code review request then it's not really a good fit for [so]. Perhaps [Codereview.SE](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to post this.

Comment: what exactly do you want to ask?

Comment: I have made some comments again. I stated my question here: The above code could limit the extension that user upload, but I tried to upload a IMAGE file, it come out an error that the file wasn't accepted, but I did add 'image/jpeg' in the array, is there any error in my code?

Comment: try printing `$_FILES['uploadfile']['type']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your `if`  condition which is following

```
if ($_FILES["uploadfile"]["error"] > 0){
      //add your code here
     //$maxsize=..
     //$acceptable_array=...
}
```